# EF Linq Query nested .ToList()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

looks like I got stuck with a nested Linq Query. I have 4 Tables which I want to join. Basically a journal has one Recipient and multiple Readers. I'd like to show the Journal with it's Recipient and all it's Readers. Here's the EF Query

```
var myJournals = (
    from s in db.Journals
    where !s.Blacklist

    join recToJournals in db.RecipientsToJournals on s.JournalID equals recToJournals.JournalID
    join recipients in db.Recipients on recToJournals.RecipientID equals recipients.RecipientID

    join reaToJournals in db.ReadersToJournals on s.JournalID equals reaToJournals.JournalID
    join readers in db.Readers on reaToJournals.ReaderID equals readers.ReaderID

    select new AnalysisViewModel
    {
        JournalID = s.JournalID,
        Title = s.Title,
        RecipientName = recipients.FullName,
        ReaderList = readers.FullName.ToList()
    });

return View(myJournals);
```

Here's the ViewModel:

```
public class AnalysisViewModel
{
    public int JournalID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<Char> ReaderList { get; set; }
    public string ReaderName { get; set; }
    public string RecipientName { get; set; }
}
```

Here I'll get an Exception `System.NotSupportedException: The method 'ToList' is not supported when called on an instance of type 'String'.`

If I use `ReaderName = readers.FullName` it works, but I get a List with multiple Journals and their Readers.
[image: List of multiple Journals with Recipient and Readers]

How can I show only one Journal with it's Recipient and all it's Readers?

Comment: remove `ToList()` it is not needed, and make it : `ReaderList = readers.FullName`

Comment: This does not make sense. Why are you calling `ToList` on a string? Why would you even want `List<char>`? Change your model so the type is of `string` and remove `ToString`

Comment: Do you mean that an AnalysisViewModel should have a List<string> property of readers instead of a scalar string? How else are you going to store a list of readers in an AnalysisViewModel? How are you intending to display the list of readers in your UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change your ViewModel

```
    public class AnalysisViewModel
    {
        public int JournalID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string RecipientFullName { get; set; }
        public List<string> ReadersFullNames { get; set; }            
    }
```

You need `GroupBy`

```
    var myJournals = from s in db.Journals
                     where !s.Blacklist

                     join recToJournals in db.RecipientsToJournals 
                       on s.JournalID equals recToJournals.JournalID
                     join recipients in db.Recipients 
                       on recToJournals.RecipientID equals recipients.RecipientID

                     join reaToJournals in db.ReadersToJournals 
                       on s.JournalID equals reaToJournals.JournalID
                     join readers in db.Readers 
                       on reaToJournals.ReaderID equals readers.ReaderID

                     select new 
                            {
                                JournalID = s.JournalID,
                                Title = s.Title,
                                RecipientFullName = recipients.FullName,
                                ReaderFullName = readers.FullName
                            };

    var result = myJournals.GroupBy(j => new { j.JournalID, j.Title, j.RecipientFullName })
                           .Select(g => new AnalysisViewModel
                                        {
                                            JournalID = g.Key.JournalID,
                                            Title = g.Key.Title,
                                            RecipientFullName = g.Key.RecipientFullName,
                                            ReadersFullNames = g.Select(r => r.ReaderFullName).ToList(),                                                
                                        }
                                  )
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much. A freakin' GroupBy.. Damn I really should get some sleep now :P

Answer (score 1):

This does not make sense. Why are you calling `ToList` on a string? Why would you even want `List<char>`? Change your model so the type is of `string` and remove `ToString`

---

Change 1 - in your linq statement

```
ReaderList = readers.FullName // remove .ToList
```

Change 2 - in your model

```
public string ReaderList { get; set; }
```

Although it is not technically wrong it is not best practice to name a property of type string (or any non collection type for that mater) with the suffix List. A more suitable name would be `ReaderName`.

Comment: and probably property name too, as it is not list :) it should be `ReaderName`

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Sorry, looks like I have to clarify the problem. What you guys told me, is what I did first. I took FullName = readers.Fullname. But this results in the above picture. One Journals has multiple Readers, so I want One Journal with all it's Readers. Like "Journal ID 1 - Recipient 1 - Reader 1,2,3,4"